# Under what terms does $r$-closedness depend on the base

Tags: general-topology

Let $B_n$ form a subbase of a topological space $X$, and let $A\subset X$.

One way to define the closedness of $A$ is to say that if $x$ satisfies that *any* arbitrary intersection of sets from $B_n$ which contain $x$ also intersects $A$ then $x\in A$.

This could be specified to saying that for knowing that $x\in A$ it suffices to check intersections of only $r$ subbasic sets, a property we'll call $r$-closedness. Clearly $r$-closedness implies $(r+1)$-closedness and closedness, but not vice versa. Given a set $A$ lets say that the minimal $r$ for which $A$ is $r$-closed is its *closedness parameter* (this terminology is not standard).

My questions are:

1. Is this notion well defined? I.e. is it impossible to find a space $X$, a subset $A\subset X$ and two subbases $B_n,B^{'}_n$ such that $A$ has different closedness parameters with respect to each base?
2. If it is not well defined in general, under what terms it is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You start with a topological space, but then it seems that you employ some metric to define $r$-closedness.

Comment: How so? All I need to define $r$-closedness is a subbase.
$A$ is $r$-closed if to check whether $x\in A$ it suffices to check that if $x\in B$ where $B$ is an intersection of $r$ different subbasic sets then $B\cap A\ne\emptyset$, this does not require a metric.

Comment: Oh. That's what you mean by length. Not an ideal choice of term, or letter for the variable. Only $r$ which is a natural number is the remainder in long division.

Comment: Oh, that might be confusing, fixed...

Comment: Good. Now I can go to sleep, knowing full well you won't post the final version of the PCF notes by the time I wake up.

Comment: They're closed to finished than you might think :) Now, lets not go off topic...

Answer (score 1):

It is not immediately well defined. The obvious reason is that we could chose our subbasis to be a basis, in which case $r$-closed is exactly the same as closed, but we may also, for example take the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2 \subset\mathbb{R}^2$. This is closed, but if we take as a subbasis the set of squares with side length two and with rational centers (just to impose countability), then the lattice is definitely not $1$ closed, although the set of pairwise intersections forms a basis so it is 2-closed.

Indeed by the above observation it seems fairly clear that since a subbasis being a basis induces equivalency of all these notions, it cannot be well-defined without being uninteresting.